# Moving sprite slowly from one point to another

Tags: libgdx

I am new to libGDX. I am trying to move a sprite from one point to another by changing the x and y of the rectangle. Can I do this gradually ?

I am currently using this to set new co-ordinates

```
batch.draw(bucketCyan, bucket.x, bucket.y);
```

Comment: `bucket.x += speedX * deltaTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is called interpolation, and there are a bunch of different ways to do it. You can either update the variables yourself using the approach noone commented with, or you can check out the Interpolation class: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Interpolation.html

Answer (score 0):

Google Universal Tween Engine. It's an easy to use interpolation "engine". It lets you modify or interpolate any values over time. It is easy to use and works well. It's worth spending some time to get familiar with.